# How can I create a quick access command in the terminal for an application

Tags: linux, terminal, command, console

I want to create a quick shorcut to a file wich is: file.py it is located in 
"/myfiles/folder1/file.py"

I want to access just typing in the the terminal: "file" this file has a working directory so I have to especify the path to. in this case the working directory is /myfiles/folder1

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is call [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html).

In your case it would be:

> alias file="/myfiles/folder1/file.py"

However it will only be for this sesion. To make it permanent you have to add the command to the `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

Comment: Thanks it works great but the the thing is the file could not load the the content on the working folder so I need to especify the working directory

Comment: Just change the alias to `cd` to the working directory first, then execute the command. Something like `alias file="cd /myfiles/folder1/ && file.py"`

Comment: excellent my friend you're the best .. God bless you